# Error state Kalman Filter from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, kalman-filter

I am trying to reproduce the algorithm explained [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/fusion/ref/imufilter-system-object.html#mw_1490283f-5f7f-4075-8caa-b519200064a9) in Python but I am facing some problems with a strange growth of some parameters.
The following is my attempt. Observe that `get_ang()` and `get_acc()` return angular velocity and acceleration along [x,y,z]-axis in **degrees/s** (but I convert this data in **radians/s**) and **m/s^2** respectively):

```
import numpy as np
import quaternion
from utils import get_ang, get_acc

#utils
Z=np.zeros([3,3])
I=np.eye(3)
EARTH_GRAVITY_MS2 = -9.80665

#sample parameters
N=1        #DecimationFactor
fs=10      #SampleRate

#noise parameters
beta=3.0462e-13      #GyroscopeDriftNoise
eta=9.1385e-5       #GyroscopeNoise
kappa=N/fs  #DecimationFactor/SampleRate
lamb=0.00019247      #AccelerometerNoise
nu=0.5        #LinearAccelerationDecayFactor
csi=0.0096236       #LinearAccelerationNoise

#other parameters initialization
lin_acc_prior=np.zeros(3)
gyro_offset=np.zeros([1,3])
Q=np.diag([0.000006092348396, 0.000006092348396, 0.000006092348396, 0.000076154354947,0.000076154354947, 0.000076154354947,0.009623610000000, 0.009623610000000, 0.009623610000000])
R=(lamb+csi+(kappa**2)*(beta+eta))*I
P=Q
q=quaternion.quaternion(1,0,0,0)                     


while(1):

    """----------------------------------------------------------Model----------------------------------------------------------"""

    """Predict orientation (q-)"""
    gyro_readings=np.array(np.radians([get_ang()])) #rad/s

    for i in range(N-1):
        gyro_readings=np.append(gyro_readings,np.radians([get_ang()]),axis=0)

    delta_phi=(gyro_readings-gyro_offset)/fs    #rad/s  
    delta_q=quaternion.from_rotation_vector(delta_phi)
    q=q*np.prod(delta_q)

    """Estimate gravity from orientation (g)"""
    r_prior=quat2rotm(q) 
    g=r_prior[:,2:3].transpose()*(-EARTH_GRAVITY_MS2)   #m/s^2

    """Estimate gravity from acceleration (g_acc)"""
    accel_readings=get_acc() #m/s^2
    g_acc=accel_readings-lin_acc_prior #m/s^2


    """----------------------------------------------------------Error Model----------------------------------------------------------"""

    "Error Model (z)"
    z=g-g_acc #m/s^2

    """----------------------------------------------------------Kalman Equations----------------------------------------------------------"""

    """Observation model (H)"""
    gx=g[0,0]
    gy=g[0,1]
    gz=g[0,2]
    g_cross=np.array([[0, gz, -gy],[-gz, 0, gx],[gy, -gx, 0]])
    H=np.block([g_cross, -kappa*g_cross, I])

    """Innovation covariance (S)""" 
    S=R+np.dot(H,np.dot(P,H.transpose()))

    """Kalman gain (K)"""
    K=np.dot(P,np.dot(H.transpose(),np.linalg.inv(S)))

    """Update error estimate covariance (P+)"""
    P=P-np.dot(K,np.dot(H,P))

    """Predict error estimate covariance (P-)"""
    D1=np.diag(np.diag(P[0:3,0:3]))   #first diagonal block P
    D2=np.diag(np.diag(P[3:6,3:6]))   #second diagonal block P
    D3=np.diag(np.diag(P[6:9,6:9]))   #third diagonal block P

    Q11=D1+kappa**2*D2+(beta+eta)*I
    Q12=(D2+beta*I)
    Q12[0,0]*=-kappa
    Q22=D2+beta*I
    Q33=nu**2*D3+csi*I

    Q=np.block([[Q11,Q12,Z],[Q12,Q22,Z],[Z,Z,Q33]])
    P=Q

    """Update posterior error (x)"""
    x=np.dot(K,z.transpose())

    """----------------------------------------------------------Correct----------------------------------------------------------"""

    """Estimate orientation (q+)"""
    theta=x[:3].transpose() #rad
    q=q*quaternion.from_rotation_vector(-theta)[0]




    """Estimate linear acceleration (lin_acc_prior)"""
    b=x[3:6].transpose() #rad/s
    lin_acc_prior = lin_acc_prior*nu-b

    """Estimate gyro offset (gyro_offset)"""
    a=x[6:].transpose()
    gyro_offset=gyro_offset-a

    """----------------------------------------------------------Compute Angular Velocity----------------------------------------------------------"""

    """Angular velocity (angular_velocity)"""
    angular_velocity=np.sum(gyro_readings,axis=0)/N-gyro_offset
```

With my IMU remaining stationary (`get_ang` returning values around `[0,0,0]` and `get_acc` returning values around `[0,0,-9.8]`) I observe anomalous growth of `gyro_offset` (probably due to not small value of `a`) resulting in a wrong computation of `delta_phi`, `delta_q`, `q` and so in a wrong estimation of `g` and `z`.

I checked my code a lot of times but I didn't found any mistake. I thought that I could misinterpret the instruction in the link above, maybe making confusion with measure units (**degrees, radians, m/s^2, g**), but even trying with different combinations I obtain a similar behaviour.

Could you please help me to find what I am missing?

P.S. It is possible to reproduce my setting putting at each step:

```
gyro_readings=np.random.normal(0,1,[1,3])/50 
accel_readings=np.array([0,0,-9.8])+np.random.normal(0,1,[3])/50
```

---

Comment: I checked the referenced PDF and found a lot of mismatches with the descriptions on the matlab page. I'm going to correct all this stuff and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, hope you could help me:)

Comment: This question is really interesting, I'll try to find enough time to solve the problem. So far I implemented the whole code in matlab, but I'm observing the same behavior as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see following problems in your code:

- when calculating `g` from the orientation matrix you multiplied it by the earth gravity. As result your observation error and hence the innovation are measured in `m/s2`. According to the documentation the filter needs the error in `units g`. So I would rather divide the `g_acc` by the earth gravity.
- when  accessing the state vector `x` you used the elements 4:6 for the linear acceleration estimation, but those elements belong to the gyro offset. The same thing is with the elements 7:9 which should be used for the acceleration, not for the gyro offset.
- when generating the test signals you used some parameters for the normal distribution to simulate the noise. I would use exactly the same noise parameters you used in the filter implementation, otherwise those two noise levels do not correspond to each other and the filter could not perform optimally.
- the formula for `Q` given on the matlab page does not correspond to the original formula in the documentation. Compare equations `10.1.23` and `10.1.24`. They involve P elements `[0,2:3,5]` and `[3,5:3,5]` respectively. In your case it means the submatrix `Q12` is not correct.

Unfortunatelly I could not run your python code to check if it works better with the suggestions above. But my matlab code showed a better performance with them.

Could you try it and post some plots?

Comment: I am trying to implement your suggestions. Anyway I would like to remark your last point: I think there is a mistyping in the documentation. As you can see, in the equation 10.1.23 the left side contains Q_bb which is P[3,5:3,5] (see equation 10.1.19) but in the right side it is replaced by P[0,2:3,5] as you noted. I think it could be an error in the trascription.
Could you please check this point?

Comment: I think you are right. Probably they mean that `Theta` and `b` don't correlate and their covariance is negligible. I'm wondering why the documentation and the matlab description have so many mismatches...

Answer (score 2):

In the link you provided under kalman equations, transpose of S is inverted to calculate kalman gain.
It seems like you didn't take the transpose of S before inverting it. in the line :

```
K=np.dot(P,np.dot(H.transpose(),np.linalg.inv(S)))
```

it should be

```
K=np.dot(P,np.dot(H.transpose(),np.linalg.inv(S.transpose())))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but S is symmetric, thus its transpose is S itself.

Comment: I remember having stability issues with my kalman filters, sometimes symmetry of S and P brakes due to floating point number errors, perhaps summing these with their transposes and dividing by two could fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you again, but I checked and I have no losses of simmetry in my computation. Therefore also with your trick I observe the same behaviour.